# PHP - How do I add a name to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am building an array (json encoded) and returning it to the caller.  My output currently looks like this:

```
[{"org_id":1,"org_name":"Org 1"},{"org_id":4,"org_name":"Org 4"}]
```

I want to add a name so that output looks like this:

```
{
  “orgs” : [
    {"org_id":1,"org_name":"Org 1"},
    {"org_id":4,"org_name":"Org 4"}
  ]
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
// if orgs were found then 
if ( is_array($orgs) && !empty($orgs) ) {

  $json_orgs = json_encode($user_orgs);

// else return an empty array 
} else {
    $user_orgs = array();
}
```

I am fairly new to OO coding, so I have not figured out how to initialize an object so that "orgs" is present.  Maybe I don't even need an object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please could you show your code that generates the first piece of JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you json encode the array, just wrap it in another one:

```
$newArray = ['orgs' => $yourCurrentArray];
```

Then you json encode the new variable instead.

If you rather not create a new array, you can simply do:

```
json_encode(['orgs' => $yourCurrentArray]);
```

This doesn't really have anything to do with OOP since you're just working with arrays. Associative arrays becomes objects when encoded into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a key, for example:

```
// variable holding your data
$data;
// return statement in your controller
return ['orgs' => $data];
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say exactly how you're generating the JSON at the moment, or from what object/variable in PHP, or with what structure (there is more than one possible way).

But in general, here's how you could do it with an associative array:

```
$data = array (
  'orgs' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'org_id' => 1,
      'org_name' => 'Org 1',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'org_id' => 4,
      'org_name' => 'Org 4',
    ),
  ),
)
```

And then json_encode that to get the JSON.

(Hint: you can simply [do the process in reverse to generate this example code from the desired JSON](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e511b9c316fdea1a31cd1a5546718ec75b95ab33).)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decode this with **json_decode()** and then you get like this

array (
0 =>
array (
'org_id' => 1,
'org_name' => 'Org 1',
),
1 =>
array (
'org_id' => 4,
'org_name' => 'Org 4',
),
)

**then you need to add parant array on it**

array( "orgs"=> array (
0 =>
array (
'org_id' => 1,
'org_name' => 'Org 1',
),
1 =>
array (
'org_id' => 4,
'org_name' => 'Org 4',
),
)
)

**then again encode it and you will get your answer**